# R output to confluence page REST API

Tags: r, rest, curl, httr, confluence-rest-api

I am new at using APIs. I have an R output in the form of a list which I want to paste on a confluence page. and I have no idea how. I have been trying to use Rest API but its confusing me.

I have been able to get a 200 response from the website using

```
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE))
URL <- "http://xxx.xx.xx/xx/xx/daily_report"
response = GET(URL, authenticate("xxx", "xxx"))
response
```

Really clueless where to go next.

Comment: If you are uploading data to some API, wouldn't they have a POST end-point to use? I think it's probably time to read the API manual. It looks like your httr code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content(response, "parsed", "application/json")$results
```